# How to add a line break in a plot title that also contains a greek letter in R

Tags: r, character-encoding, plot, title, line-breaks

This question feels like it should have a straightforward answer but I can't seem to figure it out, and for the first time, I can't find someone else who has already asked and gotten an answer to this question on the internet.

I have a plot title that has a greek letter (not a problem) as well as a line break (also not usually a problem).  But somehow, I can't get them both to work at the same time in a single plot title.

This code works fine, except that it's too long:

```
title1=expression(paste("Interannual variability in "*delta^13*"C ratios in fish samples"))
plot(1,1, main=title1)
```

This code also works fine, and inserts the line break, but it doesn't have the greek letter or the superscript:

```
title1=expression(paste("Interannual variability in d13C ratios \nin fish samples"))
plot(1,1, main=title1)
```

But this code puts the "C ratios" on the previous line.  It's so confusing.

```
title1=expression(paste("Interannual variability in "*delta^13*"C ratios\nin fish samples"))
plot(1,1, main=title1)
```

I've tried various permutations of expression, paste, and substitute but must admit that my grasp of the exact working of those functions does is patchy.  My apologies if I could have found the answer in a different way.

Any thoughts would be most welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you considered the `atop` function? (As you have discovered the "\n" character is not accepted by plotmath.)

```
title1=expression(atop(Interannual~variability~"in"~delta^13~C~ratios, 
                       "in"~fish~samples))
plot(1,1, main=title1)
```

The only thing that needs to be quoted is the "in" since it is a reserved word.

(Regarding where to find prior discussions, there should have been hits on this topic in the r-help archives.)

```
require(fortunes)
fortune("Liaw-Baron principle")
```

Comment: Much simpler than writing out each line manually. Can you left or right justify this way, or is it centered only?

Comment: There are no justification parameters, but if you want to move things around in expressions, you can add `phantom(".....")~` or `~phantom(".....")`  at either end. You would need to use `bquote` or `substitute` if you wanted that to be program-calculated based on `nchar()`.

Comment: !  Thank you for the helpful tutorial on both `atop` and quoting text.